# "Run as admin" prevents application from auto startup in windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, admin, startup, uac

I have created an application for windows 8 in C#, and because it need to create/write/read certain text files, I need to put it to "run as administrator" only it will function properly. I also need this application to auto startup after my windows8 boot up.

But seems like "run as administrator" doesn't work with auto startup in windows 8. My application won't auto startup if I put it as "run as administrator". Windows 7 and windows xp don't have this problem.

Is there any solution programmatically to this? I really need both "run as administrator" and auto startup.

Comment: Did you try editing the executable properties and setting the compatibility settings to Windows 7?

Comment: Yes. I have tried the compatibility settings to Windows 7 but it still cannot autostart.

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://superuser.com/questions/870933/how-to-have-programs-launch-on-startup-that-requires-uac-in-win-8-1

Comment: You are correct: applications configured to "run as administrator" cannot be automatically started.  This is by design, and has been true since Windows Vista.  This is because it would be too annoying for the user to be presented with one or more elevation requests each time they log in.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to be sure, but the correct solution is probably to relocate the text files in question, or change the permissions on them, so that administrator privilege is not required.  More generally, you could implement it as a system service rather than an application, or as the combination of a system service and an application.

Comment: Since Windows Vista? But how come I tested in windows 7, don't have this problem..

Comment: use the task scheduler trick to workaround the issue: https://sites.google.com/site/freeavvarea/UACPass-en

Comment: Yes. Using task scheduler is one of the solution. But this add extra work for the user as he/she has to configure the task scheduler. I'm thinking of creating an application which after install straightaway can run and no need much configuration.

Comment: #Harry Johnston, I'm thinking of maybe can relocate the files and administrator privilege is not required approach. But how do we do that?

Comment: No idea why you didn't see the same behaviour on Windows 7, you should have done.  Perhaps you had turned UAC off?  Your installer can configure the task scheduler for the user if you want to use that solution, though it will only work if the user actually has admin privilege.  How you relocate the files depends on what they are - if you're creating them yourself, then surely you can just change your code to create them in a different folder?  Preferably the user's Documents folder, or similar?

Comment: the diff between Win7 and 8 is that moving the UAC slider down, doesn't disable UAC in windows 8. This is done because the new store apps only work with UAC turned on.